# Is it necessary to change hostname following cloning to multiple machines?

Tags: 12.04, networking, cloning

I am cloning multiple laptops in a school environment with edubuntu 12.04.   There are some network issues that have resulted with machines not connecting to the wireless.  There are 130 machines in all that I have deployed.  I haven't changed the hostname.  Would that resolve the network issues?